# Able to ping, but not able to browse my LAN

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, permissions, connection

I've two laptops on my table, both connected to same Wi-Fi router. I'm able to surf the Internet on both laptops. Both laptops show each other's name in their respective explorer windows. I've installed fresh Windows 7 on both laptops (one has 32 bit, other 64 bit).

But when I double click on the other PC's name, it gives this error:

> PC2 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
>
> Logon Failure: User Account Restriction.  Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced.      <sub>(See image below.)</sub>

I found this workaround:
Just went into Control Panel → Network & Sharing Center → Change Advanced Sharing Settings → Clicked down pointing arrow (for the currently connected network type, e.g., Home or Work) → Turned Off Password Protected Sharing.

But by toggling this option, I don't want to unsafe my LAN/PCs. Can anyone guide me?

[image: Explorer → Network]

Answer (score 1):

If you won't to share all of your files with another computer, just create an extra user, assign password to this account and use its credentials when you connecting from another computer. Enable in "Network & Sharing Center" access to public folders. This way computers can share data over public folders only `C:/Users/Public/*` but still need to be authenticated.

P.S.
Important - make sure both of your computers are in home or work profile (not public) !

Comment: That's actually a clever trick. But I see no evidence from the question why must one resort to it. Still, maybe it is worth a try, since we have no other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you receive and your workaround are both indicative of a password problem.

Do the following on **both computers**:

1. Make sure any and all user accounts on both computers have a password.
2. Make sure all user accounts (or at least the ones with with you login) that have similar usernames between the two computers also have similar passwords.
3. Make sure both computers are on the same network profile: i.e. both are on the home profile or both are on the work profile.
4. Make sure password-protected sharing is enabled on both computer for all network profiles.